# Expectation of joint variables following Uniform distribution

Tags: probability, integration

I was solving a question to find an autocovariance of a sequence, and got stuck in the middle. 
$\{\lambda_{t}\}$ is a sequence of independent random variables from uniform distribution from $[-\pi,\pi]$. $i$ is the imaginary number.

The line I got stuck is this:

$E[e^{i(\lambda_{t+\tau} - \lambda_t)}]$

I think I have to solve by integration because it is in form of $E[g(\lambda_t,\lambda_{t+\tau})]$ that is expectation of two joint variables (no?) but I don't know how to do it.

Please anyone help me... Thank you.

Comment: Ohhh I think I solved it